# What may trigger a change in Excel reference style while running a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

**SOLVED - See notes below, esp. "edit 3:"**

The basic issue is this: The reference style changes (from R1C1 to A1) while the macro runs. What could trigger this? Might there be a corruption of some kind in my workbook? Are there other possible explanations?

The change means that Formulas written with R1C1 references then return an error, which causes the macro to stop running. As soon as I then make any change to any sheet (click any empty cell and press enter), reference style changes back and errors disappear.

You can recreate the effect without the macro by going to options and changing the reference style. This will also only affect sheets once you make any changes.

I've tried running it on different systems with different versions of excel and different amounts of RAM. All were set to R1C1 as standard. All switched to A1 while running the macro and returned an error.

I also tried to repeatedly set the reference style to R1C1 within the macro to counteract any changes that occur. I tried leaving out the Clear Cache bit as I hadn't used that before and wasn't sure I was using it correctly. None of that rectified the issue.

Below you find the code with a big gap and a comment where it stops running due to a type-error (because of trying to load an error value into a Double-type variable).

edit1: Thanks for the helpful comment. I have corrected that now.

edit2: To make sure I wasn't dealing with a corrupted file, I tried a new workbook, new copy of the data, new pivot tables and only copied the macro code and a small number of formulas that compile the pivot outputs into a few key figures - still get the same result.

edit3: I don't understand what causes the problem yet, but I have found a way around it. Excel changing reference types corrupts formulas using the output of `=cell("address";)`, but not of `=address(;;;0)` where the reference style can explicitly be stated. Using references of both kinds side by side and trying them out in both workbooks, I also found that the problem occurs only with the first set of slicers, while with the second, both kinds of references remain intact. In case anybody has any idea as to why that is, I am still interested. In any case, I am going to leave this here in case others run into the same problem.

```
Sub ReadWriteFastExport()

Dim Cache As SlicerCache
Dim Item As SlicerItem
Dim hs2name As String
Dim hs4name As String
Dim j, l As Integer
Dim GVolumen As Double, Konzentrationst As Double
Dim GTrend As Double, Konzentration16 As Double, GTrendinP As Double
Dim Top5VolumenWert As Variant, Top5VolumenAnteil As Variant, Top5VolumenName As Variant
Dim Top5TrendName As Variant, Top5TrentWert As Variant, Top5TrendAnteilt As Variant
Dim Flop5TrendName As Variant, Flop5TrendWert As Variant, Flop5TrendAnteilt As Variant

For Each Cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
Cache.ClearManualFilter
Next Cache
Worksheets("ExporteDashboard").Activate
    GVolumen = ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 98).Value
    GTrend = ActiveSheet.Cells(21, 98).Value
    GTrendinP = ActiveSheet.Cells(22, 98).Value
    Top5VolumenName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 98), Cells(29, 98))
    Top5VolumenWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 97), Cells(29, 97))
    Top5VolumenAnteil = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 97), Cells(41, 97))
    Top5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 99), Cells(41, 99))
    Top5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 97), Cells(35, 97))
    Top5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 98), Cells(41, 98))
    Flop5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 101), Cells(35, 101))
    Flop5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 98), Cells(35, 98))
    Flop5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(43, 98), Cells(47, 98))
    Konzentration16 = ActiveSheet.Cells(63, 96).Value
    Konzentrationst = ActiveSheet.Cells(65, 96).Value

Worksheets("Global").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Richtung"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(51, 1)) = "Export"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Wert"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "GVolumen"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "GTrend"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value = "GTrendinP"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(9, 2)) = "Top5VolumenName"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, 2), Cells(14, 2)) = "Top5VolumenWert"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, 2), Cells(19, 2)) = "Top5VolumenAnteil"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, 2), Cells(24, 2)) = "Top5TrendName"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 2), Cells(29, 2)) = "Top5TrendWert"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(30, 2), Cells(34, 2)) = "Top5TrendAnteilt"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(35, 2), Cells(39, 2)) = "Flop5TrendName"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, 2), Cells(44, 2)) = "Flop5TrendWert"
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(45, 2), Cells(49, 2)) = "Flop5TrendAnteilt"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(50, 2).Value = "Konzentration16"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 2).Value = "Konzentrationstrend"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Global"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = GVolumen
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = GTrend
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 3).Value = GTrendinP
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(9, 3)) = Top5VolumenName
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, 3), Cells(14, 3)) = Top5VolumenWert
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, 3), Cells(19, 3)) = Top5VolumenAnteil
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, 3), Cells(24, 3)) = Top5TrendName
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 3), Cells(29, 3)) = Top5TrendWert
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(30, 3), Cells(34, 3)) = Top5TrendAnteilt
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(35, 3), Cells(39, 3)) = Flop5TrendName
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, 3), Cells(44, 3)) = Flop5TrendWert
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(45, 3), Cells(49, 3)) = Flop5TrendAnteilt
    ActiveSheet.Cells(50, 3).Value = Konzentration16
    ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 3).Value = Konzentrationst



hs2name = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS2").SlicerItems(1).Name
    For Each Item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS2").SlicerItems
        If Item.Name <> ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS2").SlicerItems(1).Name Then
        Item.Selected = False
        End If
    Next Item

    Worksheets(hs2name).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Richtung"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(51, 1)) = "Export"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Wert"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "GVolumen"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "GTrend"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value = "GTrendinP"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(9, 2)) = "Top5VolumenName"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, 2), Cells(14, 2)) = "Top5VolumenWert"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, 2), Cells(19, 2)) = "Top5VolumenAnteil"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, 2), Cells(24, 2)) = "Top5TrendName"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 2), Cells(29, 2)) = "Top5TrendWert"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(30, 2), Cells(34, 2)) = "Top5TrendAnteilt"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(35, 2), Cells(39, 2)) = "Flop5TrendName"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, 2), Cells(44, 2)) = "Flop5TrendWert"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(45, 2), Cells(49, 2)) = "Flop5TrendAnteilt"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(50, 2).Value = "Konzentration16"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 2).Value = "Konzentrationstrend"
    Worksheets("ExporteDashboard").Activate





'Line at which the macro currently stops

        GVolumen = ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 98).Value
        GTrend = ActiveSheet.Cells(21, 98).Value
        GTrendinP = ActiveSheet.Cells(22, 98).Value
        Top5VolumenName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 98), Cells(29, 98))
        Top5VolumenWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 97), Cells(29, 97))
        Top5VolumenAnteil = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 97), Cells(41, 97))
        Top5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 99), Cells(41, 99))
        Top5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 97), Cells(35, 97))
        Top5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 98), Cells(41, 98))
        Flop5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 101), Cells(35, 101))
        Flop5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 98), Cells(35, 98))
        Flop5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(43, 98), Cells(47, 98))
        Konzentration16 = ActiveSheet.Cells(63, 96).Value
        Konzentrationst = ActiveSheet.Cells(65, 96).Value
    Worksheets("Global").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = hs2name
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Value = GVolumen
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4).Value = GTrend
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4).Value = GTrendinP
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(9, 4)) = Top5VolumenName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, 4), Cells(14, 4)) = Top5VolumenWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, 4), Cells(19, 4)) = Top5VolumenAnteil
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, 4), Cells(24, 4)) = Top5TrendName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 4), Cells(29, 4)) = Top5TrendWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(30, 4), Cells(34, 4)) = Top5TrendAnteilt
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(35, 4), Cells(39, 4)) = Flop5TrendName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, 4), Cells(44, 4)) = Flop5TrendWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(45, 4), Cells(49, 4)) = Flop5TrendAnteilt
        ActiveSheet.Cells(50, 4).Value = Konzentration16
        ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Value = Konzentrationst



For j = 2 To ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS2").SlicerItems.Count
    hs2name = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS2").SlicerItems(j).Name
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS2").SlicerItems(j).Selected = True
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS2").SlicerItems(j - 1).Selected = False
     Worksheets(hs2name).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Richtung"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(51, 1)) = "Export"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Wert"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "GVolumen"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value = "GTrend"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value = "GTrendinP"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(9, 2)) = "Top5VolumenName"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, 2), Cells(14, 2)) = "Top5VolumenWert"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, 2), Cells(19, 2)) = "Top5VolumenAnteil"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, 2), Cells(24, 2)) = "Top5TrendName"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 2), Cells(29, 2)) = "Top5TrendWert"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(30, 2), Cells(34, 2)) = "Top5TrendAnteilt"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(35, 2), Cells(39, 2)) = "Flop5TrendName"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, 2), Cells(44, 2)) = "Flop5TrendWert"
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(45, 2), Cells(49, 2)) = "Flop5TrendAnteilt"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(50, 2).Value = "Konzentration16"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 2).Value = "Konzentrationstrend"
    Worksheets("ExporteDashboard").Activate
        GVolumen = ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 98).Value
        GTrend = ActiveSheet.Cells(21, 98).Value
        GTrendinP = ActiveSheet.Cells(22, 98).Value
        Top5VolumenName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 98), Cells(29, 98))
        Top5VolumenWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 97), Cells(29, 97))
        Top5VolumenAnteil = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 97), Cells(41, 97))
        Top5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 99), Cells(41, 99))
        Top5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 97), Cells(35, 97))
        Top5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 98), Cells(41, 98))
        Flop5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 101), Cells(35, 101))
        Flop5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 98), Cells(35, 98))
        Flop5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(43, 98), Cells(47, 98))
        Konzentration16 = ActiveSheet.Cells(63, 96).Value
        Konzentrationst = ActiveSheet.Cells(65, 96).Value
    Worksheets("Global").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, j + 3).Value = hs2name
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, j + 3).Value = GVolumen
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, j + 3).Value = GTrend
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, j + 3).Value = GTrendinP
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, j + 3), Cells(9, j + 3)) = Top5VolumenName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, j + 3), Cells(14, j + 3)) = Top5VolumenWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, j + 3), Cells(19, j + 3)) = Top5VolumenAnteil
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, j + 3), Cells(24, j + 3)) = Top5TrendName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, j + 3), Cells(29, j + 3)) = Top5TrendWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(30, j + 3), Cells(34, j + 3)) = Top5TrendAnteilt
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(35, j + 3), Cells(39, j + 3)) = Flop5TrendName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, j + 3), Cells(44, j + 3)) = Flop5TrendWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(45, j + 3), Cells(49, j + 3)) = Flop5TrendAnteilt
        ActiveSheet.Cells(50, j + 3).Value = Konzentration16
        ActiveSheet.Cells(51, j + 3).Value = Konzentrationst

Next j

For Each Cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
Cache.ClearManualFilter
Next Cache

hs4name = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems(1).Name
    hs2name = Left(hs4name, 2)

    For Each Item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems
        If Item.Name <> ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems(1).Name Then
        Item.Selected = False
        End If
    Next Item

    Worksheets("ExporteDashboard").Activate
        GVolumen = ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 98).Value
        GTrend = ActiveSheet.Cells(21, 98).Value
        GTrendinP = ActiveSheet.Cells(22, 98).Value
        Top5VolumenName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 98), Cells(29, 98))
        Top5VolumenWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 97), Cells(29, 97))
        Top5VolumenAnteil = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 97), Cells(41, 97))
        Top5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 99), Cells(41, 99))
        Top5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 97), Cells(35, 97))
        Top5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 98), Cells(41, 98))
        Flop5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 101), Cells(35, 101))
        Flop5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 98), Cells(35, 98))
        Flop5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(43, 98), Cells(47, 98))
        Konzentration16 = ActiveSheet.Cells(63, 96).Value
        Konzentrationst = ActiveSheet.Cells(65, 96).Value
    Worksheets(hs2name).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems(k).Name
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Value = GVolumen
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4).Value = GTrend
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4).Value = GTrendinP
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(9, 4)) = Top5VolumenName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, 4), Cells(14, 4)) = Top5VolumenWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, 4), Cells(19, 4)) = Top5VolumenAnteil
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, 4), Cells(24, 4)) = Top5TrendName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 4), Cells(29, 4)) = Top5TrendWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(30, 4), Cells(34, 4)) = Top5TrendAnteilt
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(35, 4), Cells(39, 4)) = Flop5TrendName
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, 4), Cells(44, 4)) = Flop5TrendWert
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(45, 4), Cells(49, 4)) = Flop5TrendAnteilt
        ActiveSheet.Cells(50, 4).Value = Konzentration16
        ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Value = Konzentrationst
    hs2name = "empty"
For j = 2 To ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems.Count
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems(j).Selected = True
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems(j - 1).Selected = False
    hs4name = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems(j).Name
    If Left(hs4name, 2) <> hs2name Then
    l = 2
    hs2name = Left(hs4name, 2)
    Else
    l = l + 1
    End If
Worksheets("ExporteDashboard").Activate
    GVolumen = ActiveSheet.Cells(20, 98).Value
    GTrend = ActiveSheet.Cells(21, 98).Value
    GTrendinP = ActiveSheet.Cells(22, 98).Value
    Top5VolumenName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 98), Cells(29, 98))
    Top5VolumenWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, 97), Cells(29, 97))
    Top5VolumenAnteil = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 97), Cells(41, 97))
    Top5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 99), Cells(41, 99))
    Top5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 97), Cells(35, 97))
    Top5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(37, 98), Cells(41, 98))
    Flop5TrendName = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 101), Cells(35, 101))
    Flop5TrendWert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 98), Cells(35, 98))
    Flop5TrendAnteilt = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(43, 98), Cells(47, 98))
    Konzentration16 = ActiveSheet.Cells(63, 96).Value
    Konzentrationst = ActiveSheet.Cells(65, 96).Value
Worksheets(hs2name).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, l + 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt_HS4").SlicerItems(k).Name
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, l + 3).Value = GVolumen
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, l + 3).Value = GTrend
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, l + 3).Value = GTrendinP
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, l + 3), Cells(9, l + 3)) = Top5VolumenName
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(10, l + 3), Cells(14, l + 3)) = Top5VolumenWert
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(15, l + 3), Cells(19, l + 3)) = Top5VolumenAnteil
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(20, l + 3), Cells(24, l + 3)) = Top5TrendName
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(25, l + 3), Cells(29, l + 3)) = Top5TrendWert
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(30, l + 3), Cells(34, l + 3)) = Top5TrendAnteilt
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(35, l + 3), Cells(39, l + 3)) = Flop5TrendName
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, l + 3), Cells(44, l + 3)) = Flop5TrendWert
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(45, l + 3), Cells(49, l + 3)) = Flop5TrendAnteilt
    ActiveSheet.Cells(50, l + 3).Value = Konzentration16
    ActiveSheet.Cells(51, l + 3).Value = Konzentrationst
Next j




For Each Cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
Cache.ClearManualFilter
Next Cache


End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated but you need to specify the type for each variable, simply naming the variable type for the last on a line only specifies it for that one variable.